# Calling PostgreSQL Stored Procedures and Functions from Symfony 5 using Doctrine

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

After having read and searched a lot of places, even the official Doctrine documentation is no longer if it is possible to invoke stored procedures and functions of a database (PostgreSQL in my case) in Symfony through Doctrine.

For example, imagine that I want to perform a simple *greeting()* function in PosgresSQL that always returns a *"Hello"* and from Symfony I want to do the equivalent of a "***SELECT id, username, greeting () FROM user***". The result of this query I intend to show on screen in a list of 3 columns. When editing some of your rows, persist the first and second rows in the database. The third since it is a calculated column.

Obviously in the real world, the function will be somewhat more complex. I am simply trying to understand how to handle the calls to functions and procedures stored in the database. Since the project I am starting will have to make use of complex and intensive base calculations.

As I said, after consulting I am wondering if the solution is to use [Native SQL and ResultSetMapping from Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/native-sql.html#native-sql). It's the only thing that comes close to solving my problem. I see it as somewhat elaborate and I think there must be some simpler way to solve it. Come on, I want to believe that this is common and there must be simpler solutions.

Can someone guide me about it?

I apologize for my English. I have used google translation services. My native language is Spanish.

Comment: there is an extension [beberlei/doctrineextensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) that adds built-in functions to doctrine (for use in the sql/dql parser). you could add your stored function in the same manner. Alternatively (and it's probably easier in this specific use case), you could just work with the [pdo connection via `$em->getConnection()`](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L180) instead, and then just do your sql query without any verification by doctrine. (see also: https://php.net/pdo)

Comment: addendum: you  only need native query + result set mapping if you want to hydrate entity objects, which I assume you don't. working with the connection without any entities is probably better suited then ... however you lose the integration into doctrine/symfony (query will not appear in profiler, probably)

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood the question, but it seems pretty simple to me:

```
$conn = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM "myFunctionName"(:p1, :p2)');
$stmt->bindParam(':p1', $one);
$stmt->bindParam(':p2', $two);
$result = $stmt->executeQuery()->fetchAssociative();
```

Quotes around function to account for capitals in function name.